# Compile issue after splitting framework and app in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have tried to split app.js and framework.js in sencha.

**production.properties**

```
  enable.split.mode=true
```

This is working fine for creating sencha production build. But, when I run the application in device ( Android ) I'm facing the below issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'blink' of undefined
    at index.html:41
    at index.html:41
```

Could someone give technical advice on this ?

Comment: Does this app properly run on all browsers(including MAC) ?

Comment: @Tejas Oh god.. i forgot thanks i will check.